# Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?

Tags: android, string, resources

I would like to have 2 languages for the UI and separate string values for them in my resource file `res\values\strings.xml`:

```
<string name="tab_Books_en">Books</string>
<string name="tab_Quotes_en">Quotes</string>
<string name="tab_Questions_en">Questions</string>
<string name="tab_Notes_en">Notes</string>
<string name="tab_Bookmarks_en">Bookmarks</string>

<string name="tab_Books_ru">Книги</string>
<string name="tab_Quotes_ru">Цитаты</string>
<string name="tab_Questions_ru">Вопросы</string>
<string name="tab_Notes_ru">Заметки</string>
<string name="tab_Bookmarks_ru">Закладки</string>
```

Now I need to retrieve these values dynamically in my app:

```
spec.setContent(R.id.tabPage1);
String pack = getPackageName();
String id = "tab_Books_" + Central.lang;
int i = Central.Res.getIdentifier(id, "string", pack);
String str = Central.Res.getString(i);
```

My problem is that `i = 0`.

Why does not it work in my case?

Comment: Are you certain that Central.lang is either `en` or `ru`?

Comment: More info is needed to inspect your code. what is the state of each var before getting i? Anyways, you should use the default localization  support in Android to keep things simple.

Comment: Related post - [A boolean value defined in XML. How to reference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16113608/465053)

Answer (score 1246, accepted):

The link you are referring to seems to work with strings generated at runtime. The strings from strings.xml are not created at runtime.
You can get them via

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

*`getResources()` is a method of the `Context` class. If you are inside a `Activity` or a `Service` (which extend Context) you can use it like in this snippet.*

Also **note that the whole language dependency can be taken care of by the android framework**. 
Simply create different folders for each language. If english is your default language, just put the english strings into `res/values/strings.xml`. Then create a new folder `values-ru` and put the russian strings with identical names into `res/values-ru/strings.xml`. From this point on android selects the correct one depending on the device locale for you, either when you call `getString()` or when referencing strings in XML via `@string/mystring`.
The ones from `res/values/strings.xml` are the fallback ones, if you don't have a folder covering the users locale, this one will be used as default values.

See [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) and [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more information.

Comment: If you're in an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you can just call `getString(R.string.mystring)` directly.

Comment: I was just wodering. Why is it done (by google) in such a complicated way? First get numeric ID of mystring (from R object) and then getting the string by that ID? And where the pair "ID-of-mystring => actualValue" actually resides? As far as I know mystring=>ID-of-mystring is in R.java, but that is it :)

Comment: make sure that "R" is your project's R not the default android R.

Comment: This may be the answer that was needed but it wasn't the one that was asked for! For dynamically accessing a string resource by name, see the answer from @leonvian ... which should be the accepted one IMO

Answer (score 396):

Verify if your packageName is correct. You have to refer for the root package of your Android application.

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
      String packageName = getPackageName();
      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
      return getString(resId);
    }
```

Comment: In case someone has a good reason to do this (for example, data files contain a custom string that decides which resource string should be displayed, or if this string is fetched from the Internet) -- then I'd like to point out that this solution is the correct one. Especially correct the part where the resource type is `string` and not `strings`. Because that's logical (like the rest of the Android). So, thanks for that (and more), @leonvian. :-)

Comment: @Sameer to get a array by Strings just use: res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

Take a look at this oficial link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: Cool. To get rid of a separate method declaration, this can be "simplified" in such a way: `String someStringFromXML = getString(getResources().getIdentifier("some_string_name", "string", getPackageName()));`.

Comment: Thanks! This is great solution when strings fetched from Internet. I'm implementing a chat, which can deliver system messages between devices. Devices may have different language and the message must me displayed in the receiving device language.

Comment: Don't forget to handle "Resources.NotFoundException" or you might run into problems later on.

Answer (score 98):

Not from activities only:

```
public static String getStringByIdName(Context context, String idName) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    return res.getString(res.getIdentifier(idName, "string", context.getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 41):

```
getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier("propertyName", "string", getPackageName()))
```

Answer (score 29):

I would add something to the solution of leonvian, so if by any chance the string is not found among the resources (return value 0, that is not a valid resource code), the function might return something :

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources()
            .getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
    if (resId == 0) {
        return aString;
    } else {
        return getString(resId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

## Best Approach

**`App.getRes().getString(R.string.some_id)`**

### Will work Everywhere (Utils, Models also).

I have read all the answers, all answers can make your work done.

- You can use `getString(R.string.some_string_id)` in both **`Activity`** or **`Fragment`**.
- You can use `Context.getString(R.string.some_string_id)` where you don't have direct access to `getString()` method. Like `Dialog`.

## Problem

When **you don't have `Context` access**, like a method in your `Util` class.

Assume below method without Context.

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    // can't use getResource() or getString() without Context.
}
```

Now you will pass `Context` as a parameter in this method and use `getString().`

```
public void someMethod(Context context){
    ...
    context.getString(R.string.some_id);
}
```

**What i do is**

```
public void someMethod(){
    ...
    App.getAppResources().getString(R.string.some_id)
}
```

**What? It is very simple to use anywhere in your app!**

So here is a **solution** by which you can access resources from anywhere like `Util class` .

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class App extends Application {
    private static Resources resources;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        resources = getResources();
    }

    public static Resources getAppResources() {
        return resources;
    }

}
```

Add name field to your `manifest.xml` `<application` tag.

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ...
        >
        ...
    </application>
```

Now you are good to go. Use `App.getAppResources().getString(R.string.some_id)` anywhere in app.

Comment: +1 simple & clean solution. Notice bad spelling `getResourses`, the `getResources` would cause override. Also the singleton pattern seems unnecessary, possibly could be skipped. Any memory leaks problems with this solution?

Comment: @Xarvalus Does this make memory leak?

Comment: in my app all fine :) just wondering if anyone had any problem with it. I will let know If I encounter any pitfall.

Comment: @Xarvalus Memory Leak usually occur at place where an variable is being used even parent class is destroyed. Like in Activities, Fragments. I don't think it will occur in this case.

Answer (score 15):

Easier way is to use the `getString()` function within the activity.

```
String myString = getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

I think this feature is added in a recent Android version, anyone who knows the history can comment on this.

Answer (score 14):

`getResources()` works only when you're in `Activity` or `Fragment` class.

- to get access to strings resource everywhere,

use:

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.somecommonstuff)
```

Comment: It also works from application context. No Activity Context needed.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using **Kotlin**, you can define an extension function as follows:

```
fun Context.getStringResourceByName(stringName: String): String? {
    val resId = resources.getIdentifier(stringName, "string", packageName)
    return getString(resId)
}
```

And then simply use it. For example, in a Puzzles app I set the Activity title according to the image file name:

```
val stringName = "${folderName}_${assetName.substringBefore(".")}"
title = getStringResourceByName(stringName)
```

In this example I am reading string resources based on dynamic names.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have an Activity reference, you can use your context in this way:

```
getContext().getString(R.string.your_string_name);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you wannt get it inside an activity or fragmnet, then:

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.string_name);
```

If you want to get it from a class outside of activity or fragment where you don't have the activity context then use application context:

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.string_name);
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin, Leverage Extension functions

```
fun Context.getStringByName(name: String): String {
    return getString(resources.getIdentifier(name, "string", packageName))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is also a set of **predefined Android strings** such as "Ok", "Cancel" and many others - so you don't have to declare all. They're available simply by:

```
getString(android.R.string.ok)
```

(In this case, "Ok" string). BTW there are also other Android resources available like for example icons images etc.

Answer (score 3):

String myString = getString(R.string.mystring);

easy way

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in an Activity:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.your string name);
```

In other situations like fragments,... use

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.your string name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To safe, you should add:
mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.your_string);

mContext can be: context in onAttach() of Fragment or this of Activity.