# A boolean value defined in XML. How to reference in Java?

Tags: java, android, boolean

I'm trying to write some code that will reference a bool.xml file and will reference the current value inside the bool.

```
<bool name="enableQAurl">true</bool>
```

With this I want to be able to reference this in code, so that if it's set to True it does something and if false does something else. Just a simple If and else statement.

Any code references or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related post - [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7493287/465053)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
 Resources res = getResources();
 boolean enableQAurl = res.getBoolean(R.bool.enableQAurl);
```

*Source*:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: Interesting! On the contrary, to get a string from the resources is very straightforward - `getString(R.string.pref_show_bass_key)`. Initially, I thought something similar `getBool(R.bool.enableQAurl)`will work for boolean resources also but it didn't. This is a bit longer route to go through `Resources` class.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer of *kaderud's* will work perfectly. If you are not in Activity, you have to use your context.

If you are in fragment or adapter then you have to follow below.

```java
boolean enableQAurl = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.enableQAurl);
```