# Use String in Java File In Android

Tags: android

I try to load a url from string line to pass a url for my RSS feed.

current code is:

`String RSSFEEDURL = "http://feed.com/feed/";`

I add a string in the string file:

`<string name="RSSFEEDURL">http://download.yallagroup.net/en/feed</string>`

And then I try to call it from the java using this code:

`String RSSFEEDURL = getString(R.string.RSSFEEDURL);`

But it does not load. Any help with that?

Comment: getString(int) refers to XML file strings.xml. Just start over the basic Android tutorials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mentioned that `I add a string in the string file`. I am assuming that you are talking about `string.xml`. I think just searching for "How to obtain string from string.xml file" will give you lots of answers. One of the reference is see [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name) . You need to use `getResources()` for getting resources first.

```
String RSSFEEDUR = getResources().getString(R.string.RSSFEEDURL);
```

I think @shkschneider is right. It might be good for you to start with some tutorials first.