# Change set of strings based on app purpose

Tags: android

I'm building an Android app that can be used for two different purposes, say biking and running. I would like to load the sport-specific keywords given a user's preference. They could be defined in different files, like `strings_biking.xml` and `strings_running.xml` .

How can I implement this as efficient/elegant as possible? I've taken a look at locales, styles, themes and lots of other topics in the Android documentation, but nothing seems to fit well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it does not support such distinguish as per category. strings.xml are used for localization only. For your purpose, you can define some prefix/suffix to the string name. While using them in activity, create string runtime by applying that prefix/suffix and string name for biking or running or any other condition.

May be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595723/685240) can help for dynamic creation of string.