# Can you convert String version of R.id to int?

Tags: android, string, int, android-resources

As an exercise, I am building a calendar. Below is a small segment of my code. I have a `class` `MyCalendar` that `extends Activity.` 
This Activity will be linked to an XML file whose layout includes seven `TextView`s with `id`s **`R.id.day0`** thru **`R.id.day6`**.

If converted from `String` to `int`, will the Activity's `findViewById()` method recognize the `int` version of these `id`s?

```
        String Days [] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        TextView dayViews [];

        private void populateViews (){

            for (int counter = 0; counter < Days.length; counter++){
                int ID = Integer.parseInt("R.id.day"+counter);
                dayViews [counter] = (TextView) findViewById(ID);
                dayViews[counter].setText(Days[counter]);
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean strings from your `strings.xml` file?

Comment: just use `getResources().getIdentifier()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried it myself. but this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595723/1514861 suggest you can do it like this:

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
  String packageName = getPackageName();
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
  return getString(resId);
}
```

EDIT: I think you would also need to replace `"string"` with `"id"`

Comment: not quite, as we are looking for an `id` in this case, but this is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.
R class from Java are ids generated at compilation.

I would do:

```
final int[] days = { R.id.day0, R.id.day1, ... };
for (int day : days) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NO, `int ID = Integer.parseInt("R.id.day"+counter);`, what you did in there is making a representation of String to Integer, not an actual mapping from R class to xml resource.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, but it might help more people. What you can do is to call getIdentifier(), like our friends said. For that, you'll need to call it inside a loop, inserting after what value you want for a this variable, to make the string that you want for your resource ID. For exemple:

Your resources file:

```
R.string.string0
R.string.string1
R.string.string2
...
R.string.string9
```

In java:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("string"+i, "string", this.getPackageName())
    println(getResources().getString(resourceId));
}
```

Then, in your rescourceId variable, you'll have an equivalent to: R.string.string0 to R.string.string9. And, in println, you'll have the value correspondent of your resources string.

In Kotlin:

```
for (i in 0..10){
    val resourceId = this.resources.getIdentifier("string"+i, "string", this.packageName)
    println(resources.getString(resourceId))
}
```

With the same explanation that I said before.