# How to call resources with string name in android?

Tags: android, resources, mp3

I'm now trying to call the resources( in my application they are mp3 files and images).
For the mp3 file part, my code goes like this ( not working obviously!)

```
if(i==1)
{
hoho= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.univ_day1);
hoho.start();
}
else if (i==2)
{
hoho= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.univ_day2);
hoho.start();  
}
```

...

In my application, there are hundreds of mp3 file inside the application. So what I want to do is briefly summarize code into something like this.

```
hoho=MediaPlayer.crate(getApplicationContet(), R.raw.univ_day+"i"); //This also looks really awkward.
```

If I knew how to write down code just like above one. How can I handle the name of raw files and the form like "R.raw...."? If I can do, then I also can apply similar approach to the image resources.

Comment: put your audio files in the assets directory and
setup arrays of strings/filename then
 traverse it
 `AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = contex.getAssets()
                    .openFd(fileName + i);`
 

`mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());`  

`descriptor.close()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

Comment: No its not. Here question is about getting the list of media files from the res folder not the list all the string resources names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can list all the names of raw assets, which are basically the filenames without the extensions, we can do this as -

```
public void listRaw(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        Log.i("Raw Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
    }
}
```

Next you'll need to refer to them by the integer assigned to that resource name. You can get this integer as:

```
int resourceID=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);
```

This is the same int which you'd get by referring to R.raw.yourRawFileName.

In your code you can use this like -

```
hoho= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resourceID);
hoho.start();
```

Next you can apply JAVA logic to play previous current and next media files. Please let know if you need help here also.

Answer (score 6):

You can get resource id by its name using `public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)` method. 
For example:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("univ_day"+i, "raw", getPackageName());
hoho = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), id);
```

Comment: Make sure to check if `id != 0`. Since resource id 0 means that the resource was not found.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've been looking for!! :)