# Android how to access strings in string.xml file and colors in color.xml programmatically

Tags: android, string

I wanna know how to access strings & colors & dimens of xml files programmatically.

Is there any easy way to access it ???

Comment: the reason is I made TextView programmatically.

Comment: So you want to *access* the string from `strings.xml` rather than *set* it?

Comment: That's what I'm sayin ~ I need to change my question little bit. sorry

Comment: Provided the answer. Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

In an activity, you can use `getResources()` to retrieve that object, and then simply use

```
Resources res = getResources();
String string = res.getString( R.string.string_id );
int color = res.getColor( R.color.color_id )
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) of your activity to get the string, color ,etc from your **values** folder of your project.

**sample:**

```
String m_string = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name); //string xml
float m_dimension = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimension); //dimens xml
int m_color = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue); //color xml
```