# compile java variable error

Tags: java, android, variables

i am trying to build android, with a small addition, but i gave me the following errors:

> packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/cyanogenmod/ProgressBar.java:144:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : variable ram_bar_button_reset location:
>   class com.android.settings.R.string       menu.add(0, MENU_RESET, 0,
>   R.string.ram_bar_button_reset)
>                                            ^ packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/cyanogenmod/ProgressBar.java:162:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : variable ram_bar_reset location: class
>   com.android.settings.R.string
>         alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.ram_bar_reset);

when i open up the file with the correspondending lines:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{       
menu.add(0, MENU_RESET, 0,
R.string.ram_bar_button_reset)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings_backup)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);   
}
```

and:

```
private void resetToDefault() 
{       
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.ram_bar_reset);
    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.progressbar_reset_message);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{           
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{
    ProgressBarColorReset();            
}       
});         

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    alertDialog.create().show();    
}
```

can someone tell me what to do?

Comment: Double check the braces and brackets

Comment: they are all correct as far as i know

Comment: Look at the second section of code that you pasted here, there's a mismatching brace in resetToDefault() and the last section is just wrong/incomplete.

Comment: show your imports and strings.xml

Comment: Shouldnt you use  = getResources().getString(R.string.ram_bar_reset);

Comment: can you help me in the right way? i cant seem to find the mismatching brace, and also dont know what is missing...

Comment: how can i show my imports and strings.xml?

Comment: Edit your post to include the file at the bottom. And the bit that's missing is just beneath onClick(), as there's a `});`, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a string value from string.xml, you should use: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493367/3492139)

```
String myStr = getResources().getString(R.string.myStringID);
```

In your case, try

```
getResources().getString(R.string.ram_bar_reset);

alertDialog.setTitle( getResources().getString(R.string.ram_bar_reset));
alertDialog.setMessage( getResources().getString(R.string.progressbar_reset_message));
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() ;
```

Ensure, your `res\values\strings.xml` contains strings with names defined as below:

```
<resources>
    <string name="ram_bar_reset">Reset RAM Bar</string>
    <string name="progressbar_reset_message">Reset Progress Bar</string>
    <string name="ok">OK</string>
</resources>
```

---

EDIT: Final Java as requested:

**CODE BLOCK 1:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{       
menu.add(0, MENU_RESET, 0,
getResources().getString(R.string.ram_bar_button_reset))  // <---- Changed Here
    .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_settings_backup))  // <-- Changed Here
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);   
}
```

**CODE BLOCK 2:**

```
private void resetToDefault() 
{       
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle( getResources().getString(R.string.ram_bar_reset)); // <---- Changed Here
    alertDialog.setMessage( getResources().getString(R.string.progressbar_reset_message)); // <---- Changed Here
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), // <---- Changed Here
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 


    {           
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
    {
        ProgressBarColorReset();            
    }       
    });



    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),// <---- Changed Here
                                     null);
    alertDialog.create().show();    
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, can you make a new copy of the correct java lines for me, all in place?

Comment: @OwnDroid: Refer My Edit Section. The java lines have been included.

Comment: @Nishanti Grashia: is there a online manual for java somewhere? need to learn a lot more...