# Using a variable in getString()

Tags: java, android, getstring

I'm using a random number to pull a string from a resource xml, all of which have a similar beginning (they are named "quote" with a number after, so quote1, quote2, etc.

I'm trying to find a way to access them using `getResources().getString()` but I don't know how to pass that, since `getString` wants an `int`, I can't do something like

```
String quoteToGet="R.string.quote"+String.valueOf(randNum) 
//randNum is the random int generated
```

because `quoteToGet` is a string, `getString(quoteToGet)` doesn't work.

What else could I do to achieve this?

Comment: Does quote1, quote2 have similar data?. If so it would better using string array resource, inside strings.xml. Then it would be easy to retrieve data.

Comment: yet another get res id from name ... USE GOOGLE ... and yeah, still 4k3R's hint is better solution

Comment: You better use a **string-array** resource

Answer (score 0):

With this method, you should get a resource by its name.

```
private String getResStringId(String aString) {
      String packageName = getPackageName();
      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
      return getString(resId);
    }
```

Use like following:

```
String quoteToGet= getResStringId("quote"+String.valueOf(randNum));
```

Comment: i just love reputation's farmers ... it just a copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name#answer-11595723

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, i used this method for an application at least one year ago, and yes, probably i found that method on stackoverflow in that question. I don't try to increase my reputation with brutal copy/paste from another answers.

Comment: You need to add attribution to your answer to the original answer.