# I am not able to find view for Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm coming to think my problem is with my preferences not being able to load in Fragment. why i cannot access them. Here is My screenshot of error:

logcat:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeTG2.png

SettingsActivity.java

```
package com.example.poo.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new MyPreferenceFragment())
            .commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);

        // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
        // updated when the preference changes.                

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity())
    .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    } 

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

       Preference locationPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key));

       Preference unitsPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_units_key));

       prefChanged(sharedPreferences, locationPref, key);

       prefChanged(sharedPreferences, unitsPref, key);
    }

     private void prefChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Preference pref, String key) {

        if (sharedPreferences instanceof ListPreference) {
            // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
            // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).

            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) sharedPreferences;

            int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(key);

            if (prefIndex >= 0) {
                pref.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
            } else {
                pref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So any help would be appreciated! I'm trying to access below preferences in MyPreferenceFragment class but cannot. My app crashes when I press on Setting option....

```
pref_general

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_location_label"/>

 <ListPreference
    android:title="@string/pref_units_label"
    android:key="@string/pref_units_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_units_metric"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_units_values"
    android:entries="@array/pref_units_options"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is My application ScreenShot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvdCH.png)

```
strings.xml

    <string name="pref_location_label">Location</string>

    <!-- Key name for storing location in SharedPreferences [CHAR LIMIT=NONE]->

    <string name="pref_location_key" translatable=`enter code here`"false">location</string>

    <!-- Default postal code for location preference [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
    <string name="pref_location_default" translatable="false">94043</string>
```

Comment: Can you change "R.id.container"  to   "android.R.id.content" and see if the error occurs .?

Comment: It is the id of FrameLayout. Why do I need to replace ?

Comment: Clearly an issue with "R.id.container" (Your logcat points that). Show the xml where you define it..

Comment: Why I asked to replace is "android.R.id.content" gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID.So if you have any issue with fetching your container id will be solved..

Comment: ok let me try and tell you

Comment: activity_settings.xml
                                                                                            <FrameLayout  xmlns:android = 
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.poo.sunshine.SettingsActivity">

</FrameLayout>

Comment: above is the xml that I have defined

Comment: In that case you have to call "setContentView"

Answer (score 0):

You can get string from resource by following:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.pref_location_key);
```

Not:

```
getString(R.string.pref_location_key)
```

More detail: [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

Comment: I did same as u said   Preference locationPref = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_location_key));  but  still it does not work and showing same error

Comment: I think this ID (R.id.container). Where did you define it?

Comment: activity_settings.xml
                                                                                            <FrameLayout  xmlns:android = 
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.example.poo.sunshine.SettingsActivity">

</FrameLayout>

Comment: in onCreate method, before display the fragment, you should `setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)` for this activity.