# After localization android shows only numbers in programmatically set text

Tags: java, android, localization

I have experimented with localization and now for some reason the text that I am setting programmatically is getting replaced by some strange numbers (all in the same pattern 2131230xxx). In Android Studio the project shows the correct text in the preview by hovering.

Did someone had the same issue?

Comment: it's always good to share your code to help us resolve the issue

Comment: I was to quick, I extracted all the strings to the resource files to make it possible for localization but forgot to call the getresources(). I was just getting the int from the R. My bad, I'm sorry. The code for other people: `getResources().getString(R.string.fibonacci)`

Comment: to resolve this issue follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279276/4833705