# Get the value from the cursor in Android SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I used the below code to get the "place" value from the "place" column using a cursor. The value of the place in my database is a string,but It returns a number that I have no idea what it is.

here's my code:

```
meeting.setPlace(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("place")));
```

Comment: `cursor.getString` always returns a string, not a number. Sounds like you inserted the data incorrectly into the database

Comment: @cricket_007 first of all thanks for correcting my mistakes.
I think I've inserted them correctly...here it is:

contentValues.put("place",R.string.consert7_place);
db.insert(TBL_MEETING,null,contentValues);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I've inserted them correctly... here it is:
>
> ```
> contentValues.put("place",R.string.consert7_place);  
> db.insert(TBL_MEETING,null,contentValues);
> ```

`R.string.consert7_place` is an integer, not a String.

You need to use `getResources().getString(R.string.consert7_place)`

For more details, see [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

Your `cursor.getString` usage is fine.