# How to access string resource in android of text in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

It is possible duplicate as bottom link. For specific question I want to ask or to get a faster answer, see the answer in my question. Otherwise, go to the following link.

> [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

===========================================================================
My question :

I am asking this question even though there are possible duplicates but those didn't worked for me.

I am trying to access to

> strings.xml

in AlertDialog but I can't seem to make it. I have said

> .setTitle(@string/AlertTitle)

in the following code below but it didn't worked and gave out an error.
Is there any possible ways to get strings from AlertDialog or is it impossible?

Code below.

This is AlertMainActivity.java

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Add a New Task") //AlertTitle
                        .setMessage("What do you want to do next?") //AlertMessage
                        .setView(taskEditText) 
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() //Add {
                           ...
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null) //Cancel  
                           ...
                        }
```

and strings.xml

```
<string name="AlertTitle">Add a New Task</string>
<string name="AlertMessage">What do you want to do next?</string>
<string name="Add">Add</string>
<string name="Cancel">Cancel</string>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using String resources programmatically you should use

```
setTitle(getString(R.string.AlertTitle));
```

instead of

```
.setTitle(@string/AlertTitle);
```

Also for this particular case there are two methods for setting the Title. Either trough the resource id, which would be `R.string.AlertTitle` or by setting a String, which can get from `getString()`

```
.setTitle(R.string.AlertTitle);
```

see [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name) for more information. You can do `getString` instead of `getResources().getString(...)` when using it from an `Activity` or `Fragment`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are referencing string resources in Java code, the correct way to do it is: `R.string.string_name`.

So your code should work like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.AlertTitle) //AlertTitle
                    //...
```