# Trying to change a url based on the default localization language

Tags: java, android, android-studio, url

I'm trying to point to a different URL with a privacy policy in different languages, depending on the language of the device. I have the url's in a string.xml, under the key privacypolicyurl, I can't seem to get that id to show up in a java class.

`public void privacyPolicy(){
        //String url = "https://github.com/*******/MobileAppPrivacyPolicy/blob/master/MobilePrivacyPolicy.txt";
        url = R.id.pr
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(getResources().getText(R.id.privacypolicy));
        startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong method in getResources(). You have to use getString()

[Like in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

By the way, you should check previous questions for your problem before asking a new one.

Comment: Sorry, brain wasn't working to come up with a good question to search for.