# Is it possible to get a resource by a string name instead of int id?

Tags: java, android, string, android-resources

Scenario:

In strings.xml I have a list of city names with each their name in lowercase, for example:

```
<string name="london">London</string>
```

In my activity I have an array of model objects and each model object has a String variable named cityName which has the same name as its respective city name in strings.xml. For example:

```
   City {
      private String cityName;
      private String countryName;
   }
```

I want to be able to retrieve the string for each model object by passing the cityName when I call the string resource.
I know this would be illegal but something like this:

```
City city1 = new City("london", "england");
R.string.city1.getCityName();
```

I know R.string keeps all the variables as constants but is there any way to map a string to the name of the constant in R.strings?

Comment: it is possible via reflexion https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203

Comment: This solution from the thread linked by 
Daniel Nugent worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595723/5906793