# How to Get R.string in ViewModel Class of DataBinding in Android

Tags: android, data-binding, textview

I am currently using `databinding` for my android application project. I want to set the `error` message on my `CustomTextView` from `R.string.txtOldPassWordError` and set it up from another class called `ViewModelClass`.

**Here is my XML code**

```
<com.horseproject.widget.CustomEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:hint="@string/enter_old_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="@={ChangePasswordVM.userOldPassword}"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
    app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_password_lock"
    app:drawableTintCompat="@color/gray_app"
    app:error="@{ChangePasswordVM.userOldPasswordError}" />
```

**and this is ViewModelClass.java**

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    public ObservableField<String> userOldPassword = new ObservableField<>("");

    public void userPasswordChange() {

        if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(userOldPassword.get()))) {
            userOldPasswordError.set("Please enter your old password");
            return;
        } else if (userOldPassword.get().length() <= 5) {
            userOldPasswordError.set("Password should contain minimum 6 characters");
            return;
        } else {
            userOldPasswordError.set(null);
        }
    }
}
```

**and this is string from `strings.xml`**

```
<string name="select">Please Enter Old Password</string>
```

So, I want to access this string in my viewModel class and set it as error message instead of `hardcoded it directly as string`.

So how can i achieve this? I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta Version. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: getResources().getString(R.string.select);

or refer this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name

Comment: i have tried this @SagarAghara, but is says "can not resolve method 'getResources' ", thx for efforts

Comment: that is because getResources needs context. Are you using MVVM architecture by any chance. Could you not pass the string from a activity or fragment via constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create `ResourceProvider` class

```
public class ResourceProvider {

    private Context mContext;

    public ResourceProvider(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getString(int resId) {
        return mContext.getString(resId);
    }

    public String getString(int resId, String value) {
        return mContext.getString(resId, value);
    }
}
```

now go to your `ApplicationClass` and paste

```
public class YourAppName extends Application {
  // Resource Provider
    private ResourceProvider mResourceProvider;
    public ResourceProvider getResourceProvider() {
        if (mResourceProvider == null)
            mResourceProvider = new ResourceProvider(this);

        return mResourceProvider;
    }
}
```

now go to your `ChangePasswordViewModel` and create object of  ResourceProvider

```
private ResourceProvider mResourceProvider;
```

and pass it in `constroctor` of `ChangePasswordViewModel`

than you can access it by

```
 userOldPasswordError.set(mResourceProvider.getString(R.string.select));
```

Comment: is this a good approach if i want to apply Junit test on my view model @Ray?

Comment: I have heard that passing the instance of the Context to ViewModel class is not a good approach.

Comment: Implementing this approach using dagger 2 is really useful and nice! thanks!

Comment: Moreover, with that approach you will have issue with string localization

Comment: This should not be the answer, using a context in VM is a bad idea, leaks and does not play nice on screen rotations

Answer (score 13):

Using an ObservableInt worked for me. Adding this to the ViewModel

```
private final ObservableInt mErrorText = new ObservableInt(R.string.empty_text);

public ObservableInt getErrorText() {
   return mErrorText;
}
```

And just setting a new String value

```
mErrorText.set(R.string.text_not_valid);
```

In the xml add the following to the TextView

```
android:text="@{viewModel.errorText}"
```

Comment: I agree this should be the correct answer. As the accepted answer relies on the context in the view model. Is there any way the string could be cleared or set to "" using this method?

Comment: i  get     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 by applying the same

Comment: @SrishtiRoy do you have the R.string.empty_text in your strings.xml? Change to what your own string or add this
<string name="empty_text" translatable="false"/>

Comment: @AlexGray If you have the empty_text you should be able to set it to clear the textfield. You could also create a BindingAdapter that checks if the text is null or empty and in that case set the textView visibility to GONE

Comment: `ObservableInt` type does not seem to work with `"tools:error"` on `TextInputLayout`. The only thing that works is `BindableString`. How do I bind `ObservableInt` with `BindableString`?

Answer (score 3):

You can send context into the layout like this :

**XML :**

```
<!-- 
<data>
     <variable 
          name="observable"
          type="...MyBaseObservableClass"
     />
</data>
 -->

android:text="@{observable.getDescription(context)}"
```

**MyBaseObservableClass.kt :**

```
@Bindable
fun getDescription(context: Context): String {
    return context.getString(R.string.my_string)
}

fun setNewData(data: Object) {
     this.data = data
     notifyPropertyChanged(BR.description)
}
```