# android `application.resources.getString` doesn't provide proper localized value

Tags: android, localization, viewmodel

I need to set value of an UI element from string resource. It's a localized application. I thought it's going to be pretty straight forward:

```
textField.postValue(getApplication<Application>().resources.getString(R.string.text))
```

When I select the language, I set that into a `SharedPreferences`, and on `attachBaseContext`, I set that language as locale:

```
private fun Context.setAppLocale(language: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val config = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale)
        return createConfigurationContext(config)
}

override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        // read from sharedpref
        ...
        super.attachBaseContext(ContextWrapper(newBase.setAppLocale(language)))
}
```

And after selecting the language I simply restart the application.

How I'm restarting the application:

```
                editor.apply()
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
```

All the texts in my application are being updated, except for those I set from android-viewmodel using `getString`.

**Can anyone help me out here, to get the proper localized values for my application within viewmodel?**

Comment: If you swipe the app out from recents, does this happen too?

Comment: funny this is, then it returns empty string :) @TheLibrarian

Comment: My point was that I think since you start the activity immediately after `finish` - the app process might not die? - ViewModel factories are usually singletons so they are not discarded. The LiveData are still holding the previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the texts in my application are being updated, except for those I
> set from android-viewmodel using `getString`.

You can't use the Application context to get a localized String, this will always return the default String value; regardless from where this is called; `ViewModel` or somewhere else.

To get a localized String, you have to call the resources object on the activity (base) context.

The best practice is to avoid dealing with objects that have a lifecycle in `ViewModels`. `ViewModels` not intended to get resources using Context. That should be done on the View instead; obviously because you need that to update an existing UI/view; so, the UI (activity/fragment) that is associated to the `ViewModel` is the right place to do that.

If there is a need to do that in the `ViewModel`, then you'd pass the `baseContext` from the View as function parameter, and not to be stored in the `ViewModel`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628646/how-should-i-get-resourcesr-string-in-viewmodel-in-android-mvvm-and-databindi) already discussed that, you'd have a look.

Something like:

```
val textField: LiveData<...>

updateTextField(context: Context) {
    textField.postValue(context.resources.getString(R.string.text))
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right... Somehow this is the only way...

Thanks for your support