# Getting strings dynamically

Tags: android

How to get strings dynamically from strings.xml where

```
for(int=1; i<100; i++){
String podp = podp+i;
context.getString(R.string.+podp) //here I have to put podp variable
}
```

I got error identifier expected.

Comment: have a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493367/4824088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
public static String getStringByIdName(Context context, String name) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        return res.getString(res.getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName()));
}
```

And call with dynamic name, which will return value inside `<string id="podp">...</string>` tag:

```
String podp = getStringByIdName(this, "podp");
```

Comment: I tried with res.getIdentifier(podp, "string", null), but showed error int cannot be converted to string

Comment: @PiotrM. Because you use it WRONG way. `res.getIdentifier()` will return resource id `@ResId` which is an int defined inside `R.java`, not your String. You MUST call `res.getString(resId)` to get your string from this resource id.

Comment: Then I obtain error Resources.getString(int) is not applicable. Its bullshit. I declared podp as a string. Its String podp = "podp"+i+n;

Comment: @PiotrM. did it work?

Comment: yes, instead res.getString I used context.getString(.....);