# toString() shows number, not the text when I use R.string

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I am making an app in two different languages.

For the header of the app, I used this code.

```
private fun showAllResults() {
    val listOfAllResult = dbHelperI.getAllQrScannedResult()
    showResults(listOfAllResult)
    mView.tvHeaderText.text = "Recent Scanned Results"

}
```

Then I made the text on R.string, but it shows numbers, not the text. How can I use R.string on this code without error?

```
private fun showAllResults() {
    val listOfAllResult = dbHelperI.getAllQrScannedResult()
    showResults(listOfAllResult)
    mView.tvHeaderText.text = R.string.recent_scanned_results.toString()

}
```

Comment: That's not how to get the value of the `String` resource. Find some Java solutions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different overloads of `setText()` method for the [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView). You need the one that takes resource id as an argument.

```
mView.tvHeaderText.setText(R.string.recent_scanned_results)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `resources` to get the string from `Id`

```
private fun showAllResults() {
    val listOfAllResult = dbHelperI.getAllQrScannedResult()
    showResults(listOfAllResult)
    mView.tvHeaderText.text = resources.getString(R.string.recent_scanned_results)
}
```