# Why a string resource is showing as an integer?

Tags: android, string, textview, settext

I am developing an app where I have in some parts of code a

```
textview.setText(R.string.resource1 + progress + R.string.resource2);
```

but when I run the app, instead of showing the strings as words (these are words translated in some languages) the app shows something like in the textview

```
  2131755168 106(this is okay, is the variable progress) 62131755102
```

those numbers should be words in English

Comment: The `resource` is an id (i.e. number) - to fetch the actual string use `getResources().getString(R.string.resource1);` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493367/17856705  (which requires a context).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that result because you are concatenating values with mixed types, the `R.string.resource1` is an int lookup value for retrieving text (it's not the text itself). When concatenating, Java will just 'toString' those int values.

You have two options...

Option 1 (Recommended):

Define a string resource that uses format arguments, then pass the progress in. It is cleaner at the call site and more flexible than option 2 below.

```xml
<string name="progress_label">Before %1$d After</string>
```

```java
textView.setText(getString(R.string.progress_label, progress));
```

Option 2:

This is less ideal because it doesn't allow you to adapt the phrasing (if needed) for the translation.

```xml
<string name="progress_before">Before</string>
<string name="progress_after">After</string>
```

```java
String before = getString(R.string.progress_before);
String after = getString(R.string.progress_after);

textView.setText(String.format("%1$s %2$d %3$s", before, progress, after));
```

Comment: Thanks much! Your Option 1 served the purpose nicely! On a personal note, that's the stupidest, most BS nonsense I've ever heard. Considering how frequently Kotlin sneers smugly at my explicit type definitions, I would think that maybe - just maybe - it could go way out on a limb and infer that they type being returned from R. _**string**_ might carry with it the possibility of being... oh, I dunno, a _STRING_!? ...but maybe that's just me. Good gods I hate Java.