# How to textview2 getText from String resource by my textView1 is equal string name

Tags: android, string, textview

"If the value in textView1 is equal string name I want string to show textView2"
//  String Example

```
<string name="a">Apple</string>
<string name="b">Banana</string>
<string name="c">Car</string>
```

//Example
if textView1 = a
textView2 Will Show Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have `stringName` as a text in your `textView1`.
You can `fetch String value` programatically from resourses by `stringName`.

`Step1` : first fetch this both values, and store it in a variable;

```
String mTvTextStrName = textView1.getText().toString().trim();
String strValue = getStringResourceByName(mTvTextStrName);
```

use this method to fetch String value.

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String aString) {
  String packageName = getPackageName();
  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
  return getString(resId);
}
```

You can also check this values via `Log.e`.

`Step2` : Now set your `strValue` in your `textView2`.

```
// Do your code.. Show Apple
   textView2.setText(strValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and teaching.  But error show like that Cannot resolve method 'getString' in 'TextView'. I do not know much yet because I am beginner.

Comment: i edited my answer, check it again. need to fetch text strings like this : textView1.getText().toString().trim()

Comment: Thank you so much.  The first code you provided is fine.  I'm sorry for the inconvenience.  Today is the happiest day to learn android code.  Thank you.  Forgive me for saying the wrong thing.  Because I use Google Translate.

Comment: glad that this helps, please accept answer so it can also helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getIdentifier() method of getResources() like below.

```
    TextView textView1= findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2= findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    String textViewText=getResources().getString(getResources().getIdentifier(textView1.getText().toString(), "string", getPackageName()));
    textView2.setText(textViewText);
```

Referenced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17086690/9502601

Comment: Thank you for your comment and teaching. This code is work.