# get string from string resource dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two strings in string resource file and I want to display them dynamically based on the string ID I receive from the BE.

```
<string name="test_one">test one string works</string>
<string name="test_two">test one string works</string>

fun getStringFromBeStringId(beStringID: String): String {
    return stringResource(id = R.string.beStringID) //this is wrong but how to 
                                                    //achieve but is there a way to achieve this please
}
```

If I receive from BE as `test_one` I will pass it to function `getStringFromBeStringId` and should be able to receive string `test one string works` back.

how I will be using this in compose

```
text = AnnotatedString(getStringFromBeStringId(beStringID = "test_one"))
```

is this possible please

thanks in advance
R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How do I get string from resources using its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can build the resource id dynamically as follows:

`context.resources.getIdentifier(beStringID, "string", context.packageName)`

This is the id that you can pass to `stringResource(...)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve dynamically

```
fun getStringResourceByName(name: String): String {
    val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "string", packageName)
    return getString(resourceId)
}

// Usage
val myString = getStringResourceByName("my_string")
```